# Howto access JSF2 @ViewScoped beans via ExternalContext?

Tags: jsf-2

In JSF1 you can access the bean instances of your current `FacesContext` by

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext()
ev.getApplicationMap().get(beanName) // get an @ApplicationScoped bean instance
ev.getSessionMap().get(beanName) // get a @SessionScoped bean instance
ev.getRequestMap().get(beanName) // get a @RequestScoped bean instance
```

In JSF2 `@ViewScoped` has been introduced, but I can't find a corresponding `getViewMap()` method on `ExternalContext`? I am using latest JSF 2.1.1-b04.
Am i misunderstanding some aspects of a `@ViewScoped` bean? Is there another good-practice to get a `@ViewScoped` bean instance on the server side?

Thanks,
Steve

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try to eval expression ([evaluateExpressionGet](http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/E17802_01/j2ee/javaee/javaserverfaces/2.0/docs/api/javax/faces/application/Application.html#evaluateExpressionGet%28javax.faces.context.FacesContext,%20java.lang.String,%20java.lang.Class%29)):

```
context.getApplication().evaluateExpressionGet(context, "#{beanName}", BeanClass.class)
```

Comment: Works for a `@ViewScoped` bean. Thanks.

Answer (score 7):

View scoped data is stored in the [view root](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/component/UIViewRoot.html#getViewMap%28boolean%29). You can get this from the [context](http://download.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/FacesContext.html#getViewRoot%28%29).

Comment: `FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getViewRoot().getViewMap().get(beanName)` works, thanks